# Does dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier prohibit cell instance variables?

Tags: ios, uitableview

If `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` reuses cells once they've gone off screen, does that mean that an instance variables set on a cell will be overwritten as a result of its new usage?

For example, if I were to cache a cell's height in an instance variable, if the same cell was later used to show a different data item, then would the cell's height be overwritten?

Should this data, instead, be stored in an array in the table view?

Comment: Are you talking about an instance variable held within a UITableViewCell? If that's the case, I would store the cell's height in your data source.

Comment: Okay, think of the cell as a shell that displays information that you get elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make any assumptions about storing data or attributes in `UITableViewCells` for exactly the reason you identified - UIKit may or may not release the cell instance from memory when it goes off screen (assume it will be gone).

Like @hackmodford commented, a better way to specifically store information about the height of a certain cell is to manage it through a data structure in the `tableViews` `UITableViewDataSource`.  An array sounds appropriate.